# How do you get oil residue off of a menora?

Tags: chanuka, how-to, menora-chanukia, cleaning, oil

When you light olive oil in a metal [menora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menorah%5F%28Hanukkah%29), some of the oil invariably finds its way into the cracks between parts of the menora. How do you remove this residue?

Comment: for those who use wax. http://lifehacker.com/clean-and-de-wax-your-menorah-with-these-tips-1671688772

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because washing is not on topic

Comment: @kouty Per many answers to [this Meta question](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/262/the-parameters-of-jewish-life-scope), this question is on-topic.

Comment: I am sorry I was not aware of Meta question. I will retire my flag

Comment: I voted to reopen the question

Comment: @kouty If you are interested in which questions should be on topic, and think that questions like this should be off topic, check out my answers on meta [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4076/8775) and [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4077/8775).

Comment: @mevaqesh Isaac Moses created mi yodeya and he explained that it is a metaquestion.

Comment: @kouty a meta question is a question about the site. Users like you get to vote about what they think the site should be like. The question is still open and being debated.

Comment: @kouty Isaac did start Mi Yodeya, and we are all forever thankful to him for that, but his opinions about policies are worth just as much as anyone else's (including mine or yours). Don't assume an answer reflects policy just because he wrote it. Voting is a much more reliable indicator.

Comment: @DoubleAA סבבא say people in Israel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put water and dishwashing detergent in a basin; let the entire menora soak in it.

Comment: if it is silver, make sure to polish afterwards, then wrap in cloth, and store in an air-tight bag until next year.

Answer (score 3):

People have told me soaking it in ammonia also works. I soaked my oil glasses in ammonia for a couple of days and it worked pretty well. I did keep it outside while I was soaking it because of the smell and because I have little kids around.